# Dockerizing .Net Core Service with default gRPC service template is not working

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, grpc

I have created a .net core 3.1 grpc project using Visual Studio(VS) template and added docker support (targe:Linux os) to it.

With the sayhello code already in the template, I ran it with VS IDE and it worked fine and given the http default page.

However when we run it with docker build and docker run commands in console, the console shows its listening and the container is running. however service is not accessible and the error received is  site cant be reached.

I have grabbed and issued the build and run commands from the VS container tools output window, still the service is not accessible  nor the default page is shown.  Has anyone came across the same issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY "GrpcService2.csproj" .
RUN dotnet restore "GrpcService2.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN ls -R
WORKDIR "/src"
RUN dotnet build "GrpcService2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GrpcService2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrpcService2.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile ?

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk,  updated with docker file.

Comment: Why dont you run `RUN dotnet publish "GrpcService2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish` just after you do` COPY . .`, you dont need to change directory and use a new from. And is there any error in the build ? Is GrpcService2.dll generated, do an ls after on /app/publish and after `COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`

Comment: And I think your base image should be `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`

Comment: If you have the project on a public source repository I can try to help more by building myself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to look up the port that's exposed by docker. See the docker dashboard. I haven't found out how to configure a fix port. At the moment at each start of the service a new port is taken by docker...